# No computed margin for input element, but margin under metrics (and display)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input element under in a table cell as follows:

```
<td><input class="form-control input-small my-input-narrow" type="number"></td>
```

Unfortunately this cell determines the width of the column which is much wider than the width of the input element.

When I inspect the element in Chrome, the computed style tab shows:

```
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
```

However, when I go under metrics, and look at the visual, and hover over Margin, it shows a wide area as margin despite the face that it says "-" as the width of the margin. The computed style for the td shows 219px for the width (whereas the input element itself is 33px).

Do you have any suggestions for me to better understand why the rendering is so?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using a table for layout, are you? Anyway, the width of table cells is determined by the width of the entire table.

Comment: Not for layout, it is an actual table. Yep, I get that - but I got over the problem by setting the width of the cell explicitly rather than a percentage.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with padding showing up visually when all styles set padding to 0px. In this case "-" was still displayed in the metrics area. The problem was that an outer element was set to a fixed width and therefore the padding was there to fill in the gap between the inspected element and that outer element with fixed width.

If you are inspecting an element in Chrome Developer Tools and notice padding or margin when the metrics area is showing "-", then most likely this is the case.